# R: replacing a certain value in a data-frame with the mean of particular range of data

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

Despite going through many topics and comments on Stackoverflow, I could not find the answer for this question. Hope it gets answered here. Thanks.

Let us say we have a data frame like this:

```
> my_data

   year month day           pr         max        min
1  2081     1   1 5.569092e-04 -26.4920749 -24.483246
2  2081     1   2 1.777802e-04 -25.9205721 -20.451972
3  2081     1   3 1.323720e-03 -27.1527253 -10.395930
4  2081     1   4 2.137142e-03 -20.8107204  -9.002432
5  2081     1   5 7.505645e-04 -16.2825782  -8.997454
6  2081     1   6 2.812341e-03  -8.4525805  -8.973068
7  2081     1   7 3.484746e-03  -0.3836075 -16.055945
8  2081     1   8 4.613059e-04  -0.2103037 -25.410168
9  2081     1   9 7.486442e-04  -3.7030182 -27.551599
10 2081     1  10 3.175442e-03  -1.5308754 -27.882620
11 2081     1  11 2.399104e-03  -5.9834657 -24.491168
12 2081     1  12 1.833119e-03 -13.7263921 -22.745234
13 2081     1  13 3.315489e-04 -18.3818204 -22.640128
14 2081     1  14 1.180063e-04 -18.6430621 -17.468890
15 2081     1  15 2.493895e-05 -15.5209717 -16.186150
16 2081     1  16 6.260483e-05 -15.8603685 -11.547591
17 2081     1  17 2.280691e-04 -10.4212179  -7.414533
18 2081     1  18 5.984287e-04  -7.9375899  -7.400936
19 2081     1  19 7.078201e-04  -7.3717562 -13.400183
20 2081     1  20 2.017283e-03  -5.7114717 -17.213636
21 2081     1  21 9.261695e-04  -4.0757166 -18.174468
22 2081     1  22 1.107990e-03  -4.7120487 -18.968903
23 2081     1  23 1.698175e-03  -7.0420167 -17.654700
24 2081     1  24 1.468677e-03 -11.8686058 -12.688654
25 2081     1  25 5.597740e-04 -11.5570338  -9.391358
26 2081     1  26 2.446489e-04 -10.5752366  -8.349224
27 2081     1  27 1.485243e-04  -8.6466939  -7.059217
28 2081     1  28 4.694722e-04  -6.1383411 -12.353198
29 2081     1  29 3.802654e-04  -2.1109669 -15.652165
30 2081     1  30 9.396260e-04  -0.1226451 -19.592908
31 2081     1  31 2.871977e-03  -0.7997992 -22.973038
```

I want to make a new value for **max** in each row, where **max** is less than and equal to **min**.

I am using this code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(my_data)) {
   # Replace the max with the Mean of max in row i to i+10:
   my_data$max[my_data$max <= my_data$min] <- mean(my_data$max[i:(i+10)])  

}
```

But the answer would be like:

```
> head(my_data)

  year month day           pr        max        min
1 2081     1   1 0.0005569092 -12.447502 -24.483246
2 2081     1   2 0.0001777802 -12.447502 -20.451972
3 2081     1   3 0.0013237197  -7.616386 -10.395930
4 2081     1   4 0.0021371418  -7.616386  -9.002432
5 2081     1   5 0.0007505645  -7.616386  -8.997454
6 2081     1   6 0.0028123409  -8.452581  -8.973068
```

Which **does NOT** make any sense.

**It must be like :**

```
  year month day           pr        max        min
1 2081     1   1 0.0005569092   -12.447502  -24.483246
2 2081     1   2 0.0001777802   -11.286985  -20.451972 
3 2081     1   3 0.0013237197   -10.601644  -10.395930
4 2081     1   4 0.0021371418    -9.8280386  -9.002432
5 2081     1   5 0.0007505645    -9.3471523  -8.997454
6 2081     1   6 0.0028123409    -9.3087696  -8.973068
```

Your comments or answers would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

**If we use Excel, this would be the whole desired result:**

```
   year month day          pr         max        min
1  2081     1   1 0.000556909 -12.4475020 -24.483246
2  2081     1   2 0.000177780 -11.2869854 -20.451972
3  2081     1   3 0.001323720 -10.6016443 -10.395930
4  2081     1   4 0.002137142  -9.8280386  -9.002432
5  2081     1   5 0.000750565  -9.3471523  -8.997454
6  2081     1   6 0.002812341  -8.4525805  -8.973068
7  2081     1   7 0.003484746  -0.3836075 -16.055945
8  2081     1   8 0.000461306  -0.2103037 -25.410168
9  2081     1   9 0.000748644  -3.7030182 -27.551599
10 2081     1  10 0.003175442  -1.5308754 -27.882620
11 2081     1  11 0.002399104  -5.9834657 -24.491168
12 2081     1  12 0.001833119 -13.7263921 -22.745234
13 2081     1  13 0.000331549 -18.3818204 -22.640128
14 2081     1  14 0.000118006  -9.9240751 -17.468890
15 2081     1  15 0.000024900 -15.5209717 -16.186150
16 2081     1  16 0.000062600  -8.8302784 -11.547591
17 2081     1  17 0.000228069  -8.1744898  -7.414533
18 2081     1  18 0.000598429  -7.7851374  -7.400936
19 2081     1  19 0.000707820  -7.3717562 -13.400183
20 2081     1  20 0.002017283  -5.7114717 -17.213636
21 2081     1  21 0.000926170  -4.0757166 -18.174468
22 2081     1  22 0.001107990  -4.7120487 -18.968903
23 2081     1  23 0.001698175  -7.0420167 -17.654700
24 2081     1  24 0.001468677 -11.8686058 -12.688654
25 2081     1  25 0.000559774  -5.7072452  -9.391358
26 2081     1  26 0.000244649  -4.7322805  -8.349224
27 2081     1  27 0.000148524  -3.5636892  -7.059217
28 2081     1  28 0.000469472  -6.1383411 -12.353198
29 2081     1  29 0.000380265  -2.1109669 -15.652165
30 2081     1  30 0.000939626  -0.1226451 -19.592908
31 2081     1  31 0.002871977  -0.7997992 -22.973038
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly do you want to calculate?

Comment: Thanks @tmfmnk. I want to do this: if in any row, max is < = min, it must be replaced by the mean of next 10 max values (i to i+10)

Comment: @Canada2015, how are you going to use this formula if the value of `max` is < `min` in one of the last 10 rows ? Your code won't work in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just loop over the sequence and assign

```
v1 <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(my_data)), function(i) 
             mean(my_data$max[i:(min(nrow(my_data), (i+10)))]))
i1 <- with(my_data, max <= min)
my_data$max[i1] <- v1[i1]
# year month day           pr         max        min
#1  2081     1   1 5.569092e-04 -12.4475020 -24.483246
#2  2081     1   2 1.777802e-04 -11.2869854 -20.451972
#3  2081     1   3 1.323720e-03 -10.6016443 -10.395930
#4  2081     1   4 2.137142e-03  -9.8280386  -9.002432
#5  2081     1   5 7.505645e-04  -9.3471523  -8.997454
#6  2081     1   6 2.812341e-03  -8.4525805  -8.973068
#7  2081     1   7 3.484746e-03  -0.3836075 -16.055945
#8  2081     1   8 4.613059e-04  -0.2103037 -25.410168
#9  2081     1   9 7.486442e-04  -3.7030182 -27.551599
#10 2081     1  10 3.175442e-03  -1.5308754 -27.882620
#11 2081     1  11 2.399104e-03  -5.9834657 -24.491168
#12 2081     1  12 1.833119e-03 -13.7263921 -22.745234
#13 2081     1  13 3.315489e-04 -18.3818204 -22.640128
#14 2081     1  14 1.180063e-04  -9.9240751 -17.468890
#15 2081     1  15 2.493895e-05 -15.5209717 -16.186150
#16 2081     1  16 6.260483e-05  -8.8302784 -11.547591
#17 2081     1  17 2.280691e-04  -8.1744898  -7.414533
#18 2081     1  18 5.984287e-04  -7.7851374  -7.400936
#19 2081     1  19 7.078201e-04  -7.3717562 -13.400183
#20 2081     1  20 2.017283e-03  -5.7114717 -17.213636
#21 2081     1  21 9.261695e-04  -4.0757166 -18.174468
#22 2081     1  22 1.107990e-03  -4.7120487 -18.968903
#23 2081     1  23 1.698175e-03  -7.0420167 -17.654700
#24 2081     1  24 1.468677e-03 -11.8686058 -12.688654
#25 2081     1  25 5.597740e-04  -5.7072452  -9.391358
#26 2081     1  26 2.446489e-04  -4.7322805  -8.349224
#27 2081     1  27 1.485243e-04  -3.5636892  -7.059217
#28 2081     1  28 4.694722e-04  -6.1383411 -12.353198
#29 2081     1  29 3.802654e-04  -2.1109669 -15.652165
#30 2081     1  30 9.396260e-04  -0.1226451 -19.592908
#31 2081     1  31 2.871977e-03  -0.7997992 -22.973038
```

Comment: @Canada2015 It is based on the logic you provided

Comment: I just edited the answer to add the anticipated correct answer. Thanks

Comment: @Canada2015 I don't understand the issue because you said to replace only when max <= min, and 6th row is not like that

Comment: @Canada2015 Just wanted to clarify.  Is it absolute values of 'max' less than 'min'

Comment: Sorry @akrun for the wrong comment. Your code is great, however, if you print the whole result, you will see that it gives NA for Jan 25 to Jan 27. This is because of our assumption to use the next 10 values, while in those dates, we have less than 10 values for max. Do you have an idea how to solve this issue even if we do not have the exact 10 values?

Comment: @Canada2015 I know why it is NA.  The issue was that we removed the last 10 elements to make the `i+10` run.  Now, I changed it to give the full length, but only added a condition to get the min index

Comment: @Canada2015 Can you check the output now

Comment: what if we only need to replace(switch) the max and min values in a row? How should we modify the function? In other words, new max = min & new min = max. Thanks.

Comment: @Canada2015  Please post as a new question

Comment: I just asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59095411/r-how-to-to-replaceswitch-the-max-and-min-values-in-a-row-in-a-dataframe-when